# AJAX Crashes Chrome

Tags: ajax, json, google-chrome, crash

Umm.. my problem is that i want to use ajax for my chatbox but whenever i try to put ajax for no-reload refresh Chrome/Firefox Crashes down.. HERE's my code:

/*chatlog.php*/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools.js"></script>

<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$.ajaxSetup({ datatype: "html" });
$('#loaddiv').load('chatlog.php');
}, 10000);
</script>
```

/*submit.php*/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".submit").click(function(){
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var dataString = 'message'+message;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "submit.php",
                data: dataString,
                                async: false,
            });
            /*$message=$_POST['message'];
    $name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $room = $_SESSION['room'];
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];*/
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "submit.php",
   data: { message : message },
   async: false
});
```

Also put your ajaxSetup outside of the setInterval function.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ datatype: "html" });
```

Comment: @mr. shaun5.. nothing happened still the browser crashes and the chatlog.php does not refresh anymore..

Comment: I don't think your problems are isolated to the code you have posted in your question...

Comment: Add it to your question, post a link or make a jsbin.com. Also clarify what you mean by the word crash.

Comment: and the word crash is: Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

Comment: async: false - helped me. Thanks. Trying to upload ~10mb file. Chrome always crashing with async: true

Answer (score 0):

Pass your data properly, like:

```
var dataString = 'message'+message;
//Should Be
var dataString = 'message='+message;
//OR
var dataString = {'message' : message };
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `var dataString = '{message :'+message+'}';`?

Comment: @ mr.Sudhir... the browser still crasher after some time.. XD

Comment: I was wrong and the last one is correct (I think), because data wants an object not a string...